# SQL Statement that orders selected IDs first with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**team_members**

```
userid
teamid
```

**users**

```
uid
name_f
name_l
```

**friends**

```
friend_id
friend_one
friend_two
```

I use the following statement to select uid and profile_pic of the users that **belong to a certain team**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid, u.profile_pic
FROM friends f, users u, team_members m
WHERE m.teamid =$team_var
AND u.uid = m.userid
```

I also have to run the following to select the uid and profile_pic of the users **who are friends** with the logged-in user and **belong to a certain team**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid, u.profile_pic
FROM friends f, users u, team_members m
WHERE m.teamid =$team_var
AND u.uid = m.userid
AND m.userid = f.friend_two
AND f.friend_one =$session_id
```

I'm looking for a way to join these two and instead of running 2 queries, run one single query that can order and list the users who are friends with the logged-in user at the top. So let's say that a certain team has 30 users and 5 of those users are friends with the logged-in user, I would like to have the first 5 listed in the while loop following the statement to be those of the friends with the rest of the 25 randomly shown.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your friends mapping table, do you have logical duplication for friend_one and friend_two such as { {x,y}, {y,x} } ?

Comment: Yes, I do Tim. It goes as follows to record a friend connection (5 and 10 are userids): 

friend_one: 5    friend_two: 10 --
friend_one: 10   friend_two: 5

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know...I'm very much stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be solved with an outer join. You will probably not be able to use an outer join without the explicit join syntax. Here:

```
SELECT
  u.uid,
  u.profile_pic,
  (friend_id IS NOT NULL) AS is_friend
FROM team_members m
  INNER JOIN users u ON m.userid = u.uid
  LEFT JOIN friends f ON m.userid = f.friend_two AND f.friend_one = $session_id
WHERE m.teamid = $team_var
ORDER BY
  is_friend DESC,
  m.userid
```

The first two tables are joined using an inner join, so only the members of a specific team are returned (because we are filtering on `teamid`).

The `friends` table is outer-joined to the result of the previous join. More specifically, we a joining the *subset* of `friends` where `friend_one` is the current user. All rows from the previous result set are returned, but also rows from the `friends`'s subset are returned where matched. Where not matched, the `friends` columns are filled with `NULL`s.

Using the `NULL` (or rather `NOT NULL`) test, we can see which team member is a friend and which isn't. The result of the test is returned as a column and also used as a sorting criterion for the output rows.

Comment: What is the difference between `inner join` and `join` and what do you mean with `outer join`? I thought we only have `left join` or `right join` in mysql, not `outer join`.

Comment: @Tomas: `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` mean the same, the `INNER` keyword is optional. An outer join [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html "JOIN Syntax (MySQL)") is either of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`. Their complete names are `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, so, as you can see, `OUTER` is optional as well, but even without the `OUTER` word they are still outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create another column which has a value of "friend" or not "friend".  You would then use that column as an ORDER BY.  The column you create could be a subquery to determine if the other user is a friend or not.  The following code is wrong because you need to hook the data from the outer query into the subquery, but it should look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid, u.profile_pic,
EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT u.uid, u.profile_pic 
FROM friends f, users u, team_members m 
WHERE m.teamid =$team_var 
AND u.uid = m.userid 
AND m.userid = f.friend_two 
AND f.friend_one =$session_id 
) AS myColumn 
FROM friends f, users u, team_members m 
WHERE m.teamid =$team_var 
AND u.uid = m.userid 
ORDER BY myColumn
```

Comment: For friend values, I have the friends table though. And that records friend_one with a userid and friend_two with the userid of the second user so it'd be redundant it seems to create another column for a friend's value.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest this:

```
select u.uid, u.profile_pic
from team_members t
    join team_members m on t.teamid = m.teamid
    join users u on m.userid = u.uid
    left join friends f on t.userid = f.friend_one and m.userid = f.friend_two
where m.userid != t.userid
    and t.userid = $session_id -- This line can be removed to view all (test)
order by
    --t.teamid, t.userid, -- This line can be added to order all (test)
    (case when f.friend_id is null then 1 else 0 end case),
    f.friend_id, m.userid
```

I'm using explicit join syntax (which is normally recommended these days) and using that case statement in the order by to get friends to the top. I don't have MySQL running here to test it, but the syntax should be pretty standard (I'm running something very similar on SQL Server).

Comment: I see. Where would I play the team_variable in this case?

Comment: It should be unnecessary, unless someone can be on more than one team.

Comment: That's how it's setup right now. So for example, the user Bill can look at 10 teams and each team will have different members with his friends in each.